# require_once is not working (relative path)

Tags: php, require-once

I have a file structure as follows:

```
>project
 >admin
 >classes
  >class_main.php
 >templates
  >foot.php
```

Within class_main.php, I am trying to use `require_once` to require the same file, dependent on where the user is (ie, if the user is in the admin dir, `require_once "../templates/foot.php"` otherwise `require_once "./templates/foot.php"`) inside of the __destruct function of my class.

My problem is that no matter what I try, I am always receiving the same error:

> Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\project\classes/templates/foot.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\classes\class_main.php on line 22

I have tried:

- using require_once as a function
- using `dirname(__FILE__)` and `__DIR__`
- using `\` and `\\` instead of `/`

How can I do this?

The full code of the __destruct function at the moment is:

```
    function __destruct()
    {
        if($this->admtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'admin')
        {
            require_once "../templates/foot.php";
        }
        else
        {
            require_once './templates/foot.php';
        }
    }
```

To clarify, this script is located at `C:\wamp\www\project\classes\class_main.php` and the file I am trying to include is located at `C:\wamp\www\project\templates\foot.php`.

Comment: Post the actual code using `require_once` if you want some helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\wamp\www\project\classes/templates/foot.php
```

This should be self explanatory, look at back and forward slashes both in one link. This should be

```
C:\wamp\www\project\classes\templates\foot.php
```

Try with backslashes in windows Format

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned the file is located at `C:\wamp\www\project\templates\foot.php` Then why not provide the complete path

```
require_once("C:\wamp\www\project\templates\foot.php");
```

Comment: I have tried that - `require_once "..\\templates\\foot.php";` and `require_once "..\templates\foot.php";` both do not work.

Comment: `C:\wamp\www\project\classes\templates\foot.php` Does this file even exist at that very location?

Comment: Instead of messing with `\ ` and `/`, use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. That's always correct for the system you're using.

Comment: No, the file exists at `C:\wamp\www\project\templates\foot.php` - no matter how I require it, the file is never included, I always get an error like the one I posted above, or `require_once(./templates/foot.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\classes\class_main.php on line 22`

Comment: Ok, can you please post the code which is including this file? Also look at Edwin's answer below which is correct that your path is looking for file elsewhere. But you have to post some code to get a quicker answer

Answer (score 0):

Your **templates** folder is located at outside of the **classes** folder. But the error shows, it searches inside classes folder.

```
C:\wamp\www\project\classes/templates/foot.php
```

Include it correctly.

Comment: How? Am I missing a period at the beginning? I've checked, I'm sure I'm including it correctly.